# Check for consecutive appearance of conditions in python and pands

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, pandas

the goal is to to check a set of conditions after each other by avoiding for and if loops.

```
condition 1
     condition 2
        condition 3
           condition 4
```

so this statement should be True if all the conditions are satisfied 'after each other'. any ideas?

Comment: can you give an example of what you mean? some data and output?

Comment: (cond 1) & (cond 2) & (cond 3) & (cond 4) will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try `and` operator.

```
print(condition1 and condition2 and condition3 and condition4)
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, but the conditions should appear after each so it must be a sequence.
like `conditon1 than condition2 than not conditon3` etc.

Comment: Yes the above statement gets evaluated from left to right, one after another.

Comment: As per 'and' , while evaluating from left to right, if any where false, the evaluation stops and exits..and if you want to use not just say (not condition4)..